# Close all sqlalchemy database connection in Flask / Dash after request(s)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, plotly-dash

I am running into a problem that my Dash/Flask web app is using too many mysql resources when used for a longer time. Eventually the server becomes incredibly slow because it tries to keep too many database connections alive. The project started based on on this article and is still organised in a similar way: https://hackersandslackers.com/plotly-dash-with-flask/

Once I open an URL from the website each Dash callback seems to open it's own connection to the database. Apart from the callback Flask opens a database connection as well to store the user session. The amount of open connections at the same time isn't really a problem, but the fact the connections aren't closed once finished is.

I've tried different settings and ways to setup the database connection, but none of them solved the problem of open database connections after the request is finished. Eventually the database runs out of resources because it tries to keep too many database connections open and the web app becomes unusable.

I've tried

**db.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

app_engine = create_engine('databasestring', poolclass=NullPool)

db_app_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=app_engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_app_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=app_engine)
```

and
**db.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

app_engine = create_engine('databasestring', poolclass=NullPool)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=app_engine)
```

And then import the db.py session / connection into the dash app.

Depending on the contents of db.py I use it in this way in the Dash app in the callback:

**dash.py**

```
@app.callback(
    # Callback input/output
    ....
    )
def update_graph(rows):
    # ... Callback logic
    session = Session()
    domain: Domain = session.query(Domain).get(domain_id)
    /*Do stuff */
    session.close()
    session.bind.dispose()
```

I've tried to close the database connections in the **init**.py of the Flask app with @app.after_request or @app.teardown_request but none of these seemed to work either.

****init**.py**

```
@app.after_request
    def after_request(response):

        session = Session()
        session.close()
        session.bind.dispose()
        return response
```

I am aware of Flask-alchemy package and tried that one as well but with similar results. When using similar code outside of Flask/Dash closing the connections after the code is finished does seem to work.

Adding the NullPool helped to get the connections close when code is executed outside of Flask/Dash, but not within the web app itself. So something still goes wrong within Flask/Dash, but I am unable to find what.

Who can point me into the right direction?

Comment: If you are using scoped sessions you check the connection back into the pool using `Session.remove()`, not `session.close()`. Flask-SQLAlchemy does this automatically in `app.teardown_request` I think, but if you are running outside of a request context then you would need to do it manually.  Calling `engine.dispose()` isn't going to help if you have connections that have not been checked-in after use.

Comment: I've been testing the code all day and I've been able to pin point the problem to the "login_required" package from Flask where queries are made like user: User = session.query(User).get(current_user.id). I would expect those running within the request context? If not how would you close them manually?

Answer (score 1):

I've also found this issue and pin-pointed it to the `login_required` decorator. Essentially, each Dash view route has this decorator so any time the dash app is opened in Flask, it opens up a new DB connection, querying for the current user. I've brought it up on a GitHub post [here](https://github.com/okomarov/dash_on_flask/issues/26).

I tried this out (in addition to the NullPool configuration) and it worked. Not sure if it's the right solution since it disposes of the database. Try it out and let me know.

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == id).one_or_none()
    db.session.close()
    engine = db.get_engine(current_app)
    engine.dispose()

    return user
```

Comment: Yes, after this post I've also found out it had to do with the login_required decorator. But still it was hard to close all connections especially when multiple connection strings where used. I've now removed Dash from the application and switched to Flask only. This seems to work fine.